# Stack Exchange iOS app - Badge reputation difference between site and app

Tags: bug, ios-app, tag-score

When I go on my profile, I've got different reputation badge than on the application.

For example , on the site, for the iOS tag, I've got 59, but on the iOS app, I've got 72

**Website profile :** 
[image]

**Mobile profile :** 
[image]

Comment: Not a bug, explained in the dupe. (same as in android app)

Comment: Here it's the iOS app. Not sure it's a real "Duplicate" because the cause of the bug may be different

Comment: No, it's not a bug. The dev clearly explains the reasoning for the difference.

Comment: Accepted the linked the answer as it answer for this question too.